# How to bind array as argument in php?

Tags: php

Is there a way to proper accept arguments like this?

```
function xyz($x, $y, $z) {

    echo $x, $y, $z;
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
xyz($arr);
```

I would to bind values from this array as arguments in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on php 5.6+, you can use the `...` operator:

```
function xyz($x, $y, $z) {
    echo $x, $y, $z;
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
xyz(...$arr);
```

Also see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php 5.6 or higher, you can use the splat operator.

```
function xyz($x, $y, $z) {
    echo $x, $y, $z;
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
xyz(...$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use list like this:

```
function xyz($array) {
    list($x, $y, $c) = $array;
    echo $x, $y, $z;
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
xyz($arr);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (not so elegant as `...` operator but works with all php5/7 versions):

```
function xyz($x, $y, $z) {
    echo $x, $y, $z;
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
call_user_func_array('xyz', $arr);
```